# how to use a geckodriver (geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.zip ) with firefox 64 bit on window pro10?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: C:\Users\Amod Kumar Gupta\Desktop\Automation\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
    at pro.googlesearchbox.main(googlesearchbox.java:13)
```

Comment: i have use double \\ in the path also

Answer (score 0):

Once you have downloaded **geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.zip** (on Windows system) you have to unzip/extract the *geckodriver.exe* within the directory `C:\Users\Amod Kumar Gupta\Desktop\Automation\`. Next through `System.setProperty()` line you have to mention the absolute path of the **geckodriver** binary either through double back slases `(\\)` or single forward slash `(/)` as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Amod Kumar Gupta\\Desktop\\Automation\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Or

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/Amod Kumar Gupta/Desktop/Automation/geckodriver.exe");
```

Next you can initialize the *WebDriver* instance and the *Firefox Browser* as follows :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and let me know if your problem is solved.
for more details go through the link  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://seleniumhq.com");
```